# Reflection to build list of EntityTypeConfiguration for Entity Framework CPT5

Tags: c#, reflection, entity-framework-4

I don't want to have to add each mapping class manually to the ModelBuilder() so was trying to use my limited knowledge of reflection to register them. This is what I have, and this is the error I am getting:

**CODE:**

```
private static ModelBuilder CreateBuilder() {
            var contextBuilder = new ModelBuilder();
            IEnumerable<Type> configurationTypes = typeof(DatabaseFactory)
                .Assembly
                .GetTypes()
                .Where(type => type.IsPublic && type.IsClass && !type.IsAbstract && !type.IsGenericType && typeof(EntityTypeConfiguration).IsAssignableFrom(type) && (type.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes) != null));

            foreach (var configuration in configurationTypes.Select(type => (EntityTypeConfiguration)Activator.CreateInstance(type)))
            {
                contextBuilder.Configurations.Add(configuration);
            }

            return contextBuilder;
        }
```

**ERROR:**
Error   2   The type arguments for method 'System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.ConfigurationRegistrar.Add(System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.EntityTypeConfiguration)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.    C:\root\development\playground\PostHopeProject\PostHope.Infrastructure.DataAccess\DatabaseFactory.cs    67  17  PostHope.Infrastructure.DataAccess

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Original answer:**

http://areaofinterest.wordpress.com/2010/12/08/dynamically-load-entity-configurations-in-ef-codefirst-ctp5/

**The details of the implied solution:**

The above referenced article shows that you can use the `dynamic` keyword to bypass compile time type checking and thus get around the restriction of attempting to add the configuration to the generic `Add()` method of the `DbModelBuilder`. Here's a quick sample:

```
// Load all EntityTypeConfiguration<T> from current assembly and add to configurations
var mapTypes = from t in typeof(LngDbContext).Assembly.GetTypes()
               where t.BaseType != null && t.BaseType.IsGenericType && t.BaseType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(EntityTypeConfiguration<>)
               select t;

foreach (var mapType in mapTypes)
{
    // note: "dynamic" is a nifty piece of work which bypasses compile time type checking... (urgh??)
    //       Check out: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd264741%28v=vs.100%29.aspx
    dynamic mapInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(mapType);
    modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(mapInstance);
}
```

You can read more on using this keyword [on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd264741%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Your `var configuration` is of type `Type`, which is not of type `EntityTypeConfiguration`.  You'll have to provide the `Add` method an instance of `EntityTypeConfiguration`, presumably based upon your current type: `configuration`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this extension method

```
public static void RegisterEntityTypeConfiguration(this ModelBuilder modelBuilder, params Assembly[] assemblies)
    {
        var applyGenericMethod = typeof(ModelBuilder).GetMethods()
            .First(m => m.Name == nameof(ModelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration));

        var types = assemblies.SelectMany(a => a.GetExportedTypes())
            .Where(c => c.IsClass && !c.IsAbstract && c.IsPublic);

        foreach (var type in types)
        {
            foreach (var @interface in type.GetInterfaces())
            {
                if (!@interface.IsConstructedGenericType ||
                    @interface.GetGenericTypeDefinition() != typeof(IEntityTypeConfiguration<>)) continue;
                var applyConcreteMethod =
                    applyGenericMethod.MakeGenericMethod(@interface.GenericTypeArguments[0]);
                applyConcreteMethod.Invoke(modelBuilder, new[] {Activator.CreateInstance(type)});
            }
        }
    }
```